# How to animate a threeJS object using GSAP?

Tags: three.js, gsap

I have been learning threeJS just recently and can't get passed a problem. I tried to animate a extruded triangle using the GSAP library. It is just a simple animation to have the triangle move to the right but it seems I did something wrong. Any help is much appreciated.

```js
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
  75,
  window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
  0.1,
  1000
);

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// Create Triangles

var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
  color: 0xf6c12a,
  shininess: 70
});

var shape = new THREE.Shape();
shape.moveTo(0, 0);
shape.lineTo(2, 3);
shape.lineTo(4, 0);
shape.lineTo(0, 0);

var extrudeSettings = {
  steps: 5,
  depth: 1,
  bevelEnabled: true,
  bevelThickness: 0.3,
  bevelSize: 0.5,
  bevelOffset: 0,
  bevelSegments: 1
};

var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeBufferGeometry(shape, extrudeSettings);

// Sets the origin to the center of geometry for rotation
geometry.center();

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

mesh.position.x = 0;
mesh.position.y = 0;
mesh.position.z = -5;
mesh.scale.set(1.5, 1.5, 1.5);

scene.add(mesh);

gsap.to(mesh, { duration: 2, x: 300 });

camera.position.z = 5;

// Background
var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1000, 1000, 1);
var material = new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial({ color: 0x444444 });
var plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
plane.position.z = -50;
scene.add(plane);

// Lighting
var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.55);
scene.add(ambientLight);

var pointLight1 = new THREE.PointLight(0xf9eac8, 1, 100);
pointLight1.position.set(5, 10, 0);
pointLight1.castShadow = true;
pointLight1.shadow.camera.top = 20;
scene.add(pointLight1);

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
render();
```

[Here is the link to Codepen](https://codepen.io/gisdirk/pen/NWXRjzY)

Tried to put the gsap code into different position but maybe that's not the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```js
gsap.to(mesh.position, { duration: 2, x: 300 });
```

the value that you want to change is `mesh.position.x` not `mesh.x`
just add `.position` it will work

Comment: It works, thanks.

I have expanded the code a bit and now I have three meshes that rotate and move in the scene.

https://codepen.io/gisdirk/pen/BaJLwOm

Would it be possible to include those animations into a timeline but still have them to be animated at the same time? Maybe through some sort of grouping or similar...?

 

The idea is to have them to be animated first, followed by other animations as shown here in the original video. https://youtu.be/VPU4k63YLfA

Comment: this should be a good way for that `Promise.all([gsap.from(...), gsap.from(...)]).then(() => play 2nd part)`